# Download WAV from API using React and Django

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, django-rest-framework, wav

I am building a program that allows the user to upload a WAV file and change its volume by a given factor

I did some testing on the backend and it is working as expected.

So, I believe the problem lies in the React section:

```js
async function changeAudioFileSettings(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("factor", audioFactor);
    formData.append("audio_file", audioFile);

    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch(
        "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/modify-volume",
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "audio/wav",
          },
          method: "POST",
          body: formData,
        }
      );

      const url = URL.createObjectURL(await response.blob());
      console.log(url);
      setNewAudioFile(url);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    } finally {
      // set loading back to false after the request is completed
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

This is the part where I display the new modified version of the WAV file for the user download it.

```js
<div className="display-value">
            {loading ? (
              <div>Loading... </div>
            ) : (
              newAudioFile && (
                <a href={newAudioFile} download="output.wav">
                  Download
                </a>
              )
            )}
</div>
```

Right now, I can download the file but it is corrupted.

My problem is that I cannot retrieve the modified file from the API and display for the user download it.

Another thing that is important to notice is that if I change the headers I get a CORS error.